# JOIN table MySQL not joining in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to learn how to use `JOIN`, `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN` and `RIGHT JOIN`.
I have the following users and generator tables

```
users
  uid
  username
  password
  email
```

and

```
creator
  id
  uid
  g_name
  g_bio
```

But I cannot join them. I try to `JOIN` like this :

```
public function Generator($uid) {
            $g_name=mysql_real_escape_string($uid);
            $query= mysql_query ("SELECT username,g_name,g_bio FROM users JOIN creator ON users.uid = creator.uid");
            $data=mysql_fetch_array($query);

            return $data;
            }
```

But `print_r` does not show anything? What is wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happened"?

Comment: @TrippKinetics print_r does not show anything

Comment: What are your desired results? Are you trying to return all records from one table or just those that match?

Comment: Error checking is essential.  `if (!$query) echo mysql_error();` Otherwise, nothing returned from `mysql_fetch_array()` means no rows returned from the query. I note also that you aren't actually using `$g_name` since you have no `WHERE` clause.

Comment: One issue I can see is the missing connection string inside the function so the mysql_query() will not work, your connection string scope is outside the function not inside it.

Comment: @user1628449 I want results g_name,g_bio,username

Comment: Use users.username, users.g_name, users.g_bio FROM ...YOUR REST QUERY... And also use mysql_query ("...Your query..") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: @SubhojitMukherjee I try it changing nothing

Comment: Make sure user.uid and creator.uid are both integer, i mean on mysql table architecture

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty `mysql_query()` will use the last open connection, regardless of scope (which is one of its chief failings, and the biggest problem for new users of the other APIs)

Comment: @SubhojitMukherjee If i use only username like `("SELECT username FROM users JOIN creator ON users.uid = creator.uid");` this print_r(); shows me username. But if i add another columnt `g_name` it said error `unknown columnt Generator`

Comment: Use a loop to get the users, while($res=mysql_fetch_array($query)){print_r($res)}

Comment: What you used? Did you used users.username, creator.g_name, creator.g_bio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, when you are referencing two tables, you need to specify from which table you are selecting each column from:

```
SELECT 
    users.username,
    creator.g_name,
    creator.g_bio 
FROM users 
JOIN creator ON users.uid = creator.uid
```

Second, in your function, you are passing in `$uid`, and then converting it to `$g_name`, but not using it anywhere in your query. Assuming you want rows matching this value, you need to add an additional `where` condition:

```
WHERE creator.g_name = '$g_name'
```

Finally, [**don't use the `mysql_*()` functions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), instead use [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**pdo**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and utilize [**prepared statements.**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 0):

You escaped function argument $uid to $g_name but you don't use it. May be it the reason of "nothing happened" ? You should rewrite your query that way :

```
"SELECT username,g_name,g_bio FROM users
    JOIN creator ON users.uid = creator.uid
    WHERE g_name = '$g_name'"
```

Beyond that I think you better should use PDO and a parameterized queries